# Can one Named Object inherit another

Tags: jsf, cdi

In my application I have discovered that I have a lot of methods in common between my CDI managed beans, so following DRY principles I want to create a super-class that has those method in it.  Then I will have about a dozen sub-classes.

So the super class is not abstract -- it has enough functionality to write a useful page against on its own.  So I have:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class BasicBacking {
```

Is it expected that I can use this like:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SpecialBacking extends BasicBacking {
```

without any problems?   What if I change the scope such as:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBacking extends BasicBacking implements Serializable {
```

Does the CDI specification make any mention of this?  Am I asking for trouble here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Preface: those are CDI managed beans, not JSF managed beans. I fixed your question already.</sup>

As to your concrete question, [CDI specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/pdf/JSR-299-FD.pdf) chapter 4 says the following:

> ### Chapter 4. Inheritance and specialization
>
> A bean may inherit type-level metadata and members from its superclasses.
>
> Inheritance of type-level metadata by beans from their superclasses is controlled via use of the Java `@Inherited` metaannotation.
>   Type-level metadata is never inherited from interfaces implemented by a bean.

So, let's look in [`@Named` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Named.html) if it has [`@Inherited`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html?is-external=true) metaannotation:

> ### Annotation Type Named
>
> ```
> @Qualifier
> @Documented
> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
> public @interface Named
> ```

No, it hasn't. Let's check the [`@RequestScoped` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html):

> ### Annotation Type RequestScoped
>
> ```
> @Target(value={TYPE,METHOD,FIELD})
> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
> @Documented
> @NormalScope
> @Inherited
> public @interface RequestScoped
> ```

Yes, it has.

Let's look further in CDI specification chapter 4.1 for the consequences:

> ### 4.1. Inheritance of type-level metadata
>
> Suppose a class X is extended directly or indirectly by the bean class of a managed bean or session bean Y.
>
> ...
>
> - If X is annotated with a scope type Z then Y inherits the annotation if and only if Z declares the @Inherited metaannotation
>     and neither Y nor any intermediate class that is a subclass of X and a superclass of Y declares a scope type.

In your case, `ViewBacking` has an explicit scope `@ViewScoped` declared, so this will be used. If it didn't have any scope, it would have been `@RequestScoped`. If it didn't have a `@Named` either, it wouldn't be available in EL on `${viewBacking}` (but still be injectable via `@Inject` due to the scope annotation).

Comment: Hm.  Sorry I should have been able to find that normative text for myself but thanks for the thorough answer.   But it looks like the specification specifically allows me to do what I want to do so I'll go for it.  Gotta love OOP.